# How to fix odd motion blur bug (see photo)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cube that is moving and the camera is following him. At the bottom, there is a weird motion blur effect/glitch which is distracting. The solution may be to exclude that object from being motion blurred but I don't know how to do that. I am using KinoMotion  (because it takes less time to compile) but the motion blur from the Unity post-processing leads to the same results (+ a longer compile time).

[image]

[image: Script settings-1]

[image: Script settings-2]

Edit: added photos with settings

Comment: Have you tried changing the `Multiple Frame Blending` to something lower or `0` ?

Comment: Let the camera follow the cube immediately.

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad it won't let me change it to something lower than 0

Comment: Something `lower than 100` or `0`, give it a try ..

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad yeah i tried but it gives it a weird ghosting effect which does not look good